# Gitlab CI with docker-compose

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose, gitlab

There is a project
https://github.com/codeship-library/nodejs-express-todoapp

What I need to do is implement a pipeline in Gitlab using docker and review apps for getting a link for any branch pushed like http://feature_*.$projectname.example.com.
Also each build should be put in local docker registry (it is already configured).

Please give a hint if I am in a wrong direction.
Which runner should I use "shell" or "docker" ?

These configs were run once with shell runner, but then I started to get permission issues i think when git was doing cleaning.

What is the best way to implement this?

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: node:7.7.2-alpine

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - review
  - deploy

variables:
  TEST_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.example.com:4567/root/nodejs-express-todoapp:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "BUILD"
    - docker-compose build
    - docker-compose push

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "TEST"
  allow_failure: true

review:
  stage: review
  script:
    - echo "REVIEW"
  when: manual

deploy_dev:
  tags:
    - dev
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "DEPLOY"
    - docker-compose up -d
  environment:
    name: dev
    url: http://$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAME.$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN.projects.example.com:3000
  only:
  - branches

undeploy_dev:
  tags:
    - dev
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker-compose stop
  when: manual
  environment:
    name: dev
    action: stop
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:7.7.2-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN apk update && apk add postgresql

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --quiet

COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/app/
    - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://todoapp@postgres/todos
    image: registry.gitlab.example.com:4567/root/nodejs-express-todoapp

  postgres:
    image: healthcheck/postgres:alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: todoapp
      POSTGRES_DB: todos
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is your runner, `docker` with `docker-in-docker` service (dind) it is the best option.

You need to have your runner because you need to activate `privileged` mode.

To do so, in your `config.toml` on you runner, insert `privileged = true` in the `runners.docker` configuration.

```
[[runners]]
  [runners.docker]
    privileged = true
```

**By enabling `privileged`, you are effectively disabling all of the security mechanisms of containers and exposing your host to privilege escalation which can lead to container breakout.**

Anyhow, for other ways consult the public documentation. I suggest you to read it anyway, it has a lot of useful information!

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I am using image: node:latest and docker:dind in services, how do I do docker-compose? It can't find docker engine

Comment: @epema split jobs, do you things in node, create an artifact, pass to the build job where you use `docker:latest` as image